# how to write custom client side validation for yii CActiveForm field?

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have created a  Yii `CActiveForm` which has a field `experience` in it. now i have made the field `experience` required in the respective Yii model.
Now to want to make it required only a particular condition.

Let's say:

`if($entity == 'student') {
    // make experience required else make experience optional
 }`

now I can set a scenario for that purpose for server side validation. but how can I make my view show client validation for experience field as per my new condition.

Comment: `$entity` is form field?

Comment: yes........................

Answer (score -1):

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('experience', 'myRequired'),
    );
}

public function myRequired($attribute, $params)
{
    if($this->entity == 'student')
    {
       $this->addError('Experience cannot be blank.');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: i have tried this but this rule will work only when all the other rules have been validated .... it will not give error if some another field is empty

Comment: @lakshay Enable ajax validation